# Starting multiple instances and wait until they are completely started using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm starting a bunch of `EC2` `Instances` using the following code

```
def start_ec2_instances(self, instanceids):
    ec2client = boto3.resource('ec2')
    response = ec2client.start_instances(InstanceIds=instanceids)
    return
```

Now it starts successfully. However I want to use `wait_until_running` method to check the status of the instances and wait until all the instances are started.

`wait_until_running` method can be issued on single instances only? How do I wait for list of instances that has been started using `boto3`

This is what I'm doing currently. But wanted to know if there are any other ways to do it in one shot

```
def wait_until_instance_running(self, instanceids):
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
    for instanceid in instanceids:
        instance = ec2.Instance(instanceid)
        logger.info("Check the state of instance: %s",instanceid)
        instance.wait_until_running()
    return
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

- [Wait until instance is running](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.InstanceRunning) or
- [Wait until a successful state is reached](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.InstanceStatusOk)

Try this:

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
start_ec2_instances(instanceids)
waiter = ec2.get_waiter('instance_running')
waiter.wait(InstanceIds=instanceids)
```

The waiter function polls every 15 seconds until a successful state is reached. An error is returned after 40 failed checks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use EC2 client's `Waiter.wait` call to pass an array of EC2 instance Ids.

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.InstanceRunning